# Pride in or pride for

Tags: grammar

Does one say:

I have a great pride **for** my country

*or*

I have a great pride **in** my country

Answer (score 1):

You have pride **in** your country, or you are proud **of** your country. You can have love **for** your country as well as a great love **of** it. Don't mix them up.